Interrupt number for the device requesting irq
I have difficulty understanding how can I chose the right value for the interrupt property in my device tree.
Suppose that I connected RTC RV3028 to my Raspberry PI 4, in particular RV3028's INT pin is connected to RPI's GPIO4.
Looking at the rv3028 device tree bindings (section: examples) we can see something like this:
i2c {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;

    rtc@51 {
        compatible = "microcrystal,rv3028";
        reg = <0x51>;
        pinctrl-0 = <&rtc_nint_pins>;
        interrupts-extended = <&gpio1 16 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
        trickle-resistor-ohms = <3000>;
    };
};

In this case they use interrupts-extended, but from what I understand I might as well use
    interrupt-parent = <&gpio1>;
    interrupts = <16 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;

And now my question is - how can I decide what interrupt number should I use instead of 16 in this case, because I guess it's not the right interrupt number?
Is there any generic way I could follow to find out what is the right interrupt number if I connect device's INT out pin to GPIOx? Is it SoC / vendor / interrupt controller specific? If so, how can I do this for e.g. NXP's SoC's or ST?
What steps should I take to find the right number?
Once I found the right pin, I assume I should later on configure it as input, configure pull up/down and so on?
I would be grateful for any advice.

First of all, you need proper configuration for pin control (precisely for pin muxing), then you give a proper GPIO line number and type for the respective pin. This can be done by learning the actual schematics. You don't need to set pin to input as it's implied by describing it as an IRQ source.
